# How to create trigger an onKey up function on texbox key press

Tags: jquery

Hello I am new to Jquery i am using pure javascript till now.Now i am trying jquery .

HTML

```
<input id="scriptBox" type="text" onkeypress="return test(event)" />
```

Javascript

```
function test(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var tb = document.getElementById("scriptBox");
        eval(tb.value);
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to do this in jquery.

Comment: not only is eval a bad idea, but calling eval on USER INPUT is an absolutely horrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of using `eval`, but here's how to write your code in jQuery:

```
$('#scriptBox').keypress(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      eval($('#scriptBox').val());
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#scriptBox').keyup(function() {
  alert('Handler for .keyup() called.');
});
```

See
http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#scriptBox').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var tb = document.getElementById("scriptBox");
        eval(tb.value);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#scriptBox').on('keydown',function(e){
     if(e.keyCode==13){
         eval($('#scriptBox').val());
         return false;
     }
});
```

would do it for jQuery 1.7. If you are using lower versions of jQuery you would work with `.live()`
But jQuery also provides methods like `.keydown(), .keyup()` and `.keypress()`

Answer (score 0):

This will be the soln

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#scriptBox").keyup(function(){   
            if(event.which==13)
            {
                var data=$("#scriptBox").val();
                alert(data);
            }
            else
            return false;
            });
        });
```